# How to control "call requires permission..." errors in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions

I have encapsulated permission check into utility method and now I am receiving

> Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should
>   explicitly check to see if permission is available (with
>   `checkPermission`) or explicitly handle a potential
>   `SecurityException`

error.

Like this:

[image]

Is it possible to smart control this error, for example, by adding some annotation (not just completely disable checking)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to smart control this error

This is not error per se but warning generated by static code analyser, most likely by bundled [Lint](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint). If that is so, you can suppress it by using `@SuppressWarnings()` annotation. See official docs on that: [Suppressing Lint Warnings](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings)

Comment: The exact annotation was `@SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")` and was suggested just from `GUI`.